# SQL QUERY - Merge Table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a three tables. [image]

Alan1, Alan2, Alan3 are the same in all tables.I want to merge tables. The difference of the tables is the rightmost column. How should I write a SQL Query?

Comment: Use `JOIN` to combine rows with common column values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join. As commented by Barmar, the idea is to use the first 3 columns as join keys;

```
select a.*, b.alan4 as alan4b, c.alan4 as alan4c
from a
inner join b
    on  b.alan1 = a.alan1
    and b.alan2 = a.alan2
    and b.alan3 = a.alan3
inner join c
    on  c.alan1 = a.alan1
    and c.alan2 = a.alan2
    and c.alan3 = a.alan3
```

This gives you rows that are available in all 3 tables. Say you want to allow "missing" rows in `b` and/or `c`, then you need to change the two `inner join`s to `left join`s.